# matlab MINLP optimization with ga

Tags: optimization, matlab, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

I have written a program for optimizing a set of generators. I have hourly price and cost data and need to figure out when a generator should run or just stay off. There are additional constraints but that is the main problem.

I am using matlabs ga function from the global optimization toolbox to try and solve this problem since it is non-linear as well as an integer problem.

However when I try to solve I get the following error:

Error using ga (line 285) 
Number of variables (NVARS) must be a positive integer.

can someone please point to the source of this error? I do not know which variables it means which need to be >0

many thanks,
Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"nvars: Positive integer representing the number of variables in the problem."*

It is an integer not a matrix.

Comment: aaaah, indeed i was just missing the variable. must be getting too late. thank you